# Visual Studio NuGet: Download the official package instead of pre-release

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm trying to import and install a NuGet package (in this case, protobuf-net) to one of our projects. When i search for this package in NuGet package manager, the version that's displayed is (at this moment)

> 2.1.0-alpha-1 (Prerelease)

I've also noticed similar things with json.net and other libraries (they point to alpha/beta releases).

I do not want to import this version and would rather install the latest stable version instead. I know that I can do this from the package manager console directly after finding out the version number from their website but I was wondering if there was:

1. Either a way to force VS to show the stable versions only and ignore showing alpha/beta releases OR
2. Show all the available releases for a certain project so that I could choose which one I want to install.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Don't know about vs2013 but vs2015 has a checkbox next to Filter called "Include prerelease". Uncheck this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about vs2013 but vs2015 has a checkbox next to Filter called "Include prerelease". Uncheck this.

See Screenshot[image: NuGet Versions]

Answer (score 2):

This is already the default behavior.

`install-package protobuf-net` will give you the latest stable release.

If you want the prerelease you must explicitly state this in the install command:

```
install-package protobuf-net -pre
```

Comment: Thanks David. It was a drop down in VS that I had somehow missed. I knew I could do it from the console but I wanted to see if I could do it from the package manager GUI. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For stable versions:

```
Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter protobuf-net -Source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ -AllVersions -IncludePrerelease | where {$_.Id -eq "protobuf-net"}
```

For prerelease versions:

```
Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter protobuf-net -Source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ -AllVersions | where {$_.Id -eq "protobuf-net"}
```

Unfortunately this does not show all versions (but should). The best method is to go to official NuGet web site, choose version and install it explicitly:

```
Install-Package protobuf-net -Version 2.0.0.668
```